# Using Configuration Settings in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am learning about ASP.NET 5. One of the areas that has me really confused is configuration. For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to load a value from the configuration file in a class. Before ASP.NET 5, I would just use:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyName"];
```

However, now with ASP.NET 5, I'm a little confused. Currently, I have the following in Startup.cs:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment environment)
{
  var configuration = new Configuration()
      .AddJsonFile("config.json");                
  Configuration = configuration;
}
```

This seems to load the configuration settings just fine. However, lets say I have a class called "Customer.cs" which interacts with the database. The database connection string is in config.json. How do I get that value? It doesn't seem efficient to load "config.json" in all of my POCOs. At the same time, the approach above doesn't seem to allow me to access `Configuration` in a global manner.

How should I load configuration settings and retrieve the configuration values in my POCOs?

Thank you

Comment: Is this for a particular type of application such as a web application?

Comment: Have you looked at the security implications of having the [connection string](http://joshowens.me/environment-settings-and-security-with-meteor-js/) in this [file](https://blog.sucuri.net/2012/11/psa-sftpftp-password-exposure-via-sftp-config-json.html)?

Comment: @lloydm Yes, this is for a web application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not load the connection string in each POCO entity (Have you ever used a DB Context?). If you're using Entity Framework 7 you can load the database context service when your app starts.

If your `config.json` looks like this:

```
"Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
        "Connectionstring": "your_connection_string"
    }
```

you can set up your environment like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add EF services to the services container

    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<Your__DB__Context__Class>(options =>
                        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString")));
    }

    //... other services...
}
```

Then in your controller you can directly use the DbContext through dependency injection:

```
public class Your__Controller : Controller
{
    [FromServices]
    public Your__DB__Context__Class DbContext { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

If you need to use the DbContext service outside from the controller you have to do like this:

```
class NotAControllerClass : NotAController
{
    private readonly Your__DB__Context__Class _dbContext;

    public NotAControllerClass(Your__DB__Context__Class DbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = DbContext;
    }

    //do stuff here...
}
```

Finally if you're not using EF7 but instead a prevoious version of EF or a custom ORM you need a custom dependency injection. Try to search it on the internet.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm trying to understand how to load configuration settings in an app. I chose to use the db connection string as that is a common setting. However, I'd like to understand how to load some random configuration setting in a POCO.